# Common HTTPclient and proxy

Tags: java, post, proxy, get, httpclient

I am using apache's common httpclient library. Is it possible to make HTTP request over proxy? More specific, I need to use proxy list for multithreaded POST requests (right now I am testing with single threaded GET requests).

I tried to use:

```
        httpclient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy("67.177.104.230", 58720);
```

I get errors with that code:

```
21.03.2012. 20:49:17 org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
21.03.2012. 20:49:17 org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
21.03.2012. 20:49:19 org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
21.03.2012. 20:49:19 org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
21.03.2012. 20:49:21 org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
21.03.2012. 20:49:21 org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProtocolException: The server xxxxx failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1846)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1590)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:995)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectMethod.execute(ConnectMethod.java:144)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeConnect(HttpMethodDirector.java:495)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:390)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
    at test.main(test.java:42)
```

When I remove that line, everything runs fine as expected.

Comment: It is indeed possible.  In your exception, which host is the redacted `xxxxx`?  Your proxy or the destination?  Why do you have so many connections refused?  Is your proxy actually working properly?

Comment: xxxxx is server where I am sending request, not proxy. Proxy should work. I am using socks5 type of proxy.

Comment: You've configured an HTTP proxy, not a SOCKS proxy.  SOCKS isn't supported by HttpClient 3.  You may be able to use the system properties 'socksProxyHost' and 'socksProxyPort'.  Or HttpComponents HttpClient 4 may support SOCKS proxies.

Comment: Even if I use use http/https proxies, I get a lot of errors. Really don't know what is wrong. I tried both HttpComponents and Commons HttpClient

Comment: What are the new errors?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:453)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.updateSecureConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:200)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.layerProtocol(AbstractPoolEntry.java:278)`
 ...

Comment: "21.03.2012. 20:49:17 org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect"
I don't want this message to be shown on the screen. How to do this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For httpclient 4.1.x you can set the proxy like this (taken from [this example](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteProxy.java)):

```
    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 8080, "http");

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);

        HttpHost target = new HttpHost("issues.apache.org", 443, "https");
        HttpGet req = new HttpGet("/");

        System.out.println("executing request to " + target + " via " + proxy);
        HttpResponse rsp = httpclient.execute(target, req);
        ...
    } finally {
        // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
        // shut down the connection manager to ensure
        // immediate deallocation of all system resources
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: I don't use new HTTP components, I am using commons httpclient. Maybe I should transfer...

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but this worked like charm for my internal development settings. Many thanks and have an upvote.

Answer (score 12):

Here is how to do that with the last version of `HTTPClient` (4.3.4)

```
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        HttpHost target = new HttpHost("localhost", 443, "https");
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 8080, "http");

        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setProxy(proxy)
                .build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("/");
        request.setConfig(config);

        System.out.println("Executing request " + request.getRequestLine() + " to " + target + " via " + proxy);

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, request);
        try {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Where do set credentials for Proxy user / pass. Sorry not sure on this.

Comment: You may take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252946/apache-http-client-4-3-credentials-per-request

Comment: How can I use 'CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();' from tomcat ? I have a servlet which calls static function that suppose to send an http request to another server

Answer (score 8):

Starting from Apache HTTPComponents 4.3.x HttpClientBuilder class sets the proxy defaults from System properties `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort` or else you can override them using setProxy method.

Answer (score 7):

Although this question is very old, but I see still there are no exact answer. I will try to answer the question here.

I believe the question in short here is how to set the proxy settings for the Apache commons HttpClient (org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient).

Code snippet below should work :

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HostConfiguration hostConfiguration = client.getHostConfiguration();
hostConfiguration.setProxy("localhost", 8080);
client.setHostConfiguration(hostConfiguration);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I solved this problem for the old (< 4.3) HttpClient (which I cannot upgrade), using the answer of Santosh Singh (who I gave a +1):

```
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
if (System.getProperty("http.proxyHost") != null) {
  try {
    HostConfiguration hostConfiguration = httpclient.getHostConfiguration();
    hostConfiguration.setProxy(System.getProperty("http.proxyHost"), Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("http.proxyPort")));
    httpclient.setHostConfiguration(hostConfiguration);
    this.getLogger().warn("USING PROXY: "+httpclient.getHostConfiguration().getProxyHost());
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new ProcessingException("Cannot set proxy!", e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with `HttpClient` version 4.

I couldn't connect to the server because of a SOCKS proxy error and I fixed it using the below configuration:

```
client.getParams().setParameter("socksProxyHost",proxyHost);
client.getParams().setParameter("socksProxyPort",proxyPort);
```

Comment: This answer helped me after hours of search.. thanks a trillion indeed!

Answer (score 0):

If your software uses a `ProxySelector` (for example for using a PAC-script instead of a static host/port) and your HTTPComponents is version 4.3 or above then you can use your `ProxySelector` for your `HttpClient` like this:

```
ProxySelector myProxySelector = ...;
HttpClient myHttpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRoutePlanner(new SystemDefaultRoutePlanner(myProxySelector))).build();
```

And then do your requests as usual:

```
HttpGet myRequest = new HttpGet("/");
myHttpClient.execute(myRequest);
```