# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, github

I have imported repository from git and performed maven build. When I run my project with "clean install -U -Denvironment.type=dev -P autoInstallPackage -P analysis -P analysisCI" goals it throws following errors. Can some one please help me solving this.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000052811d2e, pid=6564, tid=7972

# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_79-b15) (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x3f1d2e]

# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\amummadi\git\kpmg-advisory\hs_err_pid6564.log

# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It is an [internal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357557/what-is-an-internal-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I've occasionally had this happen to me. Never did figure out why. But I figured out that I could fix things by completely cleaning out my maven repo cache. (And then, of course, suffer maven's famous "download-the-world" experience on my next build.)

Comment: [INFO] HttpMethodDirector - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
[INFO] HttpMethodDirector - Retrying request
[INFO] HttpMethodDirector - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
[INFO] HttpMethodDirector - Retrying request
[INFO] HttpMethodDirector - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
[INFO] HttpMethodDirector - Retrying request

Answer (score 0):

I moved Eclipse from one SSD disk partition to another partition of the same SSD, to the root. The program is working!

Answer (score -1):

This means that your Java installation files are probably corrupted with relation to the repositories files or the installation files being used by your installer.

**Typical Solution**

Attempt to reinstall the JRE on your computer. This is easiest by doing:

> 1. Click the Start button.
> 2. Select Control Panel.
> 3. Click Programs | Uninstall a program.
> 4. In the Search box on the top right corner, type “Java”
> 5. Right click “Java Runtime Environment” from the Search Results, select Uninstall option.

**Alternatively**

This may be an error with the installation package associated with your installer which might mean you need to rebuild your installer, though I have only had to deal with this scenario once before with an installation package our company produced.

Comment: I still get below errors [INFO] HttpMethodDirector - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
[INFO] HttpMethodDirector - Retrying request
[INFO] HttpMethodDirector - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
[INFO] HttpMethodDirector - Retrying request
[INFO] HttpMethodDirector - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
[INFO] HttpMethodDirector - Retrying request

Comment: Add this to your question. Put **EDIT:** And then post that below it.

Comment: That's a proxy error of some sort. Here take a look at this stack question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811828/common-httpclient-and-proxy.

This is getting outside of my area of knowledge however and I must excuse myself from giving an incorrect answer and wait for someone with more knowledge to answer your question.