# Java - Generating Views with Proxys

Tags: java, networking, proxy, view

so im trying to generate Views on a personal page for some hours now. Im not getting why it isnt working. So my current code: (Yes im using the spigot API but that does not matter now).

```
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender cs, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if(args.length == 2){
        String link = args[0];
        String views = args[1];
        int view = 0;
        try{
            view = Integer.parseInt(views);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            cs.sendMessage("" + views + " is not a number.");
        }

            execute(link, view);


        }else{
        System.out.println("More arguments");
    }
    return true;
}
private int o = 1;
private void execute(String link, int views){

    new BukkitRunnable() {
        int i = views;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            i--;


            try{
                String fullProxy = Viewbot.getInstance().getProxys().get(i);
                String proxy, port;
                String[] fullProx;
                fullProx = fullProxy.split(":");
                proxy = fullProx[0];
                port = fullProx[1];




            /*  Proxy proxyCon = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxy, Integer.parseInt(port)));
                HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection)new URL(link).openConnection(proxyCon);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/xml, application/xml");
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");        
                */
                Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
                systemProperties.setProperty("http.proxyHost",proxy);
                systemProperties.setProperty("http.proxyPort",port);
                systemProperties.setProperty("https.proxyHost",proxy);
                systemProperties.setProperty("https.proxyPort",port);
                    URL server = new URL(link);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)server.openConnection();
                    connection.setUseCaches(false);
                    connection.connect();
                    System.out.println("Respone: "+ connection.getResponseMessage());

                    System.out.println("View #" + o + " gesendet!");
                    o++;
                            connection.disconnect();


                            System.out.println("Proxy: " + proxy + " Port: " + port);
                            System.out.println("System using: " + systemProperties.getProperty("http.proxyHost") + ":" + systemProperties.getProperty("http.proxyPort"));
                            System.out.println("Proxy: " + connection.usingProxy());


            }catch(Exception ex){
                Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Viewbot.getInstance().failProxys.add(systemProperties.getProperty("http.proxyHost") + ":" + systemProperties.getProperty("http.proxyPort"));
            }
            if(i == 5){
                for(int i = 0; i < Viewbot.getInstance().failProxys.size(); i++){
                    String failed = Viewbot.getInstance().failProxys.get(i);
                    Viewbot.getInstance().getProxys().remove(failed);


                }
                Path file = Paths.get(Viewbot.getInstance().getDataFolder() + "/HTTPS.txt");
                try {
                    Files.write(file, Viewbot.getInstance().getProxys(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("File saved");
            }
            if(i == 0){
                cancel();
            }

        }
    }.runTaskTimerAsynchronously(Viewbot.getInstance(), 0, 2);




}
```

A sample output of that whole thing:

```
[00:34:45 INFO]: Response: OK
[00:34:45 INFO]: View #430 sent!
[00:34:45 INFO]: Proxy: 41.76.44.76 Port: 3128
[00:34:45 INFO]: System using: 45.63.16.86:8080
[00:34:45 INFO]: Proxy: false
```

The output now is:

```
[00:57:58 INFO]: Proxy: 36.80.34.225 Port: 3128
[00:57:58 INFO]: System using: 113.18.193.26:8000
[00:57:58 INFO]: Proxy: true
[00:57:58 INFO]: Respone: OK
```

But when you look here: http://84.200.122.107/ It does not add views..

So its using a different IP Address to connect. Whats the error than?
It also shows that it isn't using a proxy, which should be wrong..
Thanks for any help.

Comment: systemProperties.setProperty("http.proxyHost",proxy); is JVM-wide. Don't you have another thread setting different values ?

Comment: I haven't thats the only one in the whole Project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you iterate over the list of proxy, each call to BukkitRunnable will take a new one.

So if call to BukkitRunnable in different threads overlap, one set the value and the other reads it.

To use one proxy per connection you should use common http client that is able to do it :

[Common HTTPclient and proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811828/common-httpclient-and-proxy)